# How To Replace $\rightarrow$ by $==$ in Mathematica's Output when using Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I want to create equations out of the output (solutions) produced by Mathematica when using the Solve functions. For argument's sake, consider the following.

```
Solve[{x^2+y==2,y==1},{x,y}]
```

Mathematica produces the output

```
{{x -> -1, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 1}}
```

I want to automatically replace $\rightarrow$ by $==$ in the solutions produced by Mathematica and define it as an equation:

```
equation={{x==-1,y==1}, {x==1,y==1}};
```

Thanks, Radz.

Comment: You do just like you said in the title.  Use a rule on the rules: `Rule -> Equal`.

Comment: Dear wxffles, Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach is to use a `Rule` to replace the `Rule`...

```
equation = Solve[{x^2 + y == 2, y == 1}, {x, y}] /. Rule -> Equal
```

> `{{x==-1,y==1},{x==1,y==1}}`

Here, `Rule` is the full form of the arrow `->`.

Comment: Dear Jens, Thanks.