# Modifying list operation

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list

```
lis={Subscript[g, -2][0] -> -(1/2), Subscript[g, -1][0] -> -(3/2), 
 Subscript[g, 0][0] -> 1/4 (-126 - \[Pi]^2), 
 Subscript[g, 1][0] -> 1/12 (-90 - 9 \[Pi]^2 + 16 Zeta[3])}
```

How I can modify this list by removing each of the `->`  and substituting `==` instead?

Comment: `Equal @@@ lis` where `lis` is your list.

Comment: Or `lis /. Rule -> Equal`

Comment: Or `Block[{Rule = Equal}, lis]`

Comment: Or `Thread[(Apply[List, lis[[All, 1]]]) == (Apply[List, lis[[All, 2]]])]`

Comment: Or `Inner[Equal, (Apply[List, lis[[All, 1]]]), (Apply[List, 
   lis[[All, 2]]]), List]`

Comment: Or `Diagonal@
 Outer[Equal, Apply[List, lis[[All, 1]]], Apply[List, lis[[All, 2]]]]`

Comment: Or `Cases[lis,Rule[a_,b_]:>a==b]`

Comment: @Nasser we have 7 already...3 more to go

Comment: @bmf when kglr wakes up, he could add the last three variations :)

Comment: `r1 = ReplaceAll[Rule[Rule, Equal]]@lis;
r2 = lis // ReplaceAll[Rule[Rule, Equal]];
r3 = KeyValueMap[Equal, Association@lis];
r4 = Keys[lis] == Values[lis] // Thread;
r1 == r2 == r3 == r4`

Comment: A slight variant of @Nasser's response: `Cases[lis, rule_Rule :> Equal @@ rule]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Replace $\rightarrow$ by $==$ in Mathematica's Output when using Solve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66434/how-to-replace-rightarrow-by-in-mathematicas-output-when-using-solve)